# Unable to find data that already inside beautifulsoup parser

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml

I am scraping product details from newegg website. I tried to scrape the price from right sidebar.Inside the soup as lxml format it's exists(see the Image 1) but when I tried to get that sidebar using find method from the soup it's don't display all the data(see the Image 2).

What is the reason behind this?

**Image and code are below

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKKHu.png)
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sh770.png)

```
headers = {"User-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36"}
url = link
data = re.get(url,headers=headers)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(data.content, 'lxml')

title = soup.find("div", {"class":"wrapper"}).text
price = soup.find("div", {"id":"continueReal"})
```

Comment: share the actual url/link please

Comment: I already solved the issue, thanks for comment

Answer (score 1):

You can extract from itemprop attribute with value price

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.newegg.com/black-msi-gl-series-gl73-9rcx-030-gaming-entertainment/p/N82E16834155245?Item=N82E16834155245&Tpk=N82E16834155245')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('[itemprop=price]')['content'])
print(soup.select_one('#grpDescrip_34-155-245').text.strip())
```

Or try and use same xhr request pages makes you can find in network tab.